# display: table-cell alignment issues when images are used

Tags: css, css-tables

omg this is driving me mad. I have one table-row containing two table-cells. if both cells contain only text it works just fine, but the moment I put an image on one "cell", the other cell jumps to align at baseline... even though they are in different divs.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dWgjk/)

halpl!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify vertical align..

```
.table-cell { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    }
​
```

Comment: i swear i tried that long before even considering posting here. argh. thanks!

Comment: FYI: I had to apply the vertical-align: top to the table-cell div containing the image. THAT made the text in the adjacent table-cell div with the text start aligning vertically, instead of appearing to clear (force the text down below the image).

Answer (score 0):

But the image is aligned by baseline too, by default!
Just use `display: table-cell;` (or any other) for *table-cell* style.